# Imacros how to make wilcard?

Tags: imacros

I am beginning user of imacros for firefox,
I have all updated, and tried to record this macro to load next page.
In one instance *next page* link is:
TAG POS=**1**, in another TAG POS=**2**.
I tried to use wildcard * instead of number 1 or 2, but didn't work.
What is a way to make wildcard, so imacros can click the link regardless is it **TAG POS=1** or **TAG POS=2**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, this could help you (but without a wildcard):

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
TAG POS=1 ...
TAG POS=2 ...
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 6
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

Use a different identifier for what iMacros needs to click on:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Button*
```

**Explanation from documentation:**

Tag line as recorded by iMacros:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/kb/ki.dll/ke.kb.gz?kbb;532452&&2&&&&&nc ATTR=NAME:zipcode CONTENT=85250
```

If you record the same macro a second time you will see that we get the same TAG line except one number - this is the session ID the website is using.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/kb/ki.dll/ke.kb.gz?kbb;532244&&2&&&&&nc ATTR=NAME:zipcode CONTENT=85250
```

Replace the session ID with *:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/kb/ki.dll/ke.kb.gz?kbb;*&&2&&&&&nc ATTR=NAME:zipcode CONTENT=85250
```

Actually, you could also remove most or all of the static parts of the FORM information as well. Exactly how much you can remove depends on the website. You still need enough information for iMacros to uniquely identify the page element. In our example, the result looks like:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/kb/* ATTR=NAME:zipcode CONTENT=85250
```

or even

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:* ATTR=NAME:zipcode CONTENT=85250
```

Note: TXT:* is not the same as TXT: (without *). If only TXT: is used, this means you are looking for an element where the text attribute is "", if you are using TXT:* this means that the text attribute can have any value (= same as omitting the text attribute altogether). This applies to any attribute, not just TXT.

Sources:
http://wiki.imacros.net/Form_Filling#Wildcards
http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?t=11663